# Code example to clarify non-blocking async. code - is it correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand async code so I coded up the following example. It takes a synchronous hashing algorithm using the node.js crypto module and inserts it into a promise in the hopes this doesn't block.

Does the following code run outside of the event loop? I believe it gets queued in the microtask queue?

From my example code below, the following output appears:

```
hello
hello2
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

This suggests to me that it's non-blocking as hello2 appears before the output of the hash function, but I wanted to check w/the community to ensure I understand things correctly.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

async function hash(data) {
        let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const algo = crypto.createHash('sha256');
                const upd = algo.update(data);
                const digest = upd.digest('hex');
                resolve(digest);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        console.log(await p);
}

console.log('test1');
hash('hello');
console.log('test2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you've done there is delay the hash function by one microtask - it might not even be put off until the next event loop.

Once it starts executing, it **will** block the event loop for the duration of its execution, because **JavaScript is single-threaded**. The only way around this is to use worker threads to put the processing load on another thread.

Comment: How does util.promisify work? Does it do anything differently than what I've done?

Comment: @Gary It just provides a way of wrapping old functions that were made async using callbacks instead of promises. JavaScript is single-threaded, absolute end of story - so any raw processing load you won't get off of that one thread unless you explicitly send it to another process or worker thread.

Comment: I see, thank you @Klaycon. I will have to run a task queue and execute jobs outside of node.js.